# Django - global name 'modelo' is not defined

Tags: python, django, forms, model

i have gone through some of the possible answers to this problem but with no success. I have the following model with the estoque app:

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    CAMISA = "CM"
    QUADRO = "QD"
    CANECA = 'CN'
    ESCOLHAS_PRODUTO = (
        (CAMISA, 'Camisa'),
        (QUADRO, 'Quadro'),
        (CANECA, 'Caneca'),
    )
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length = 40,
                            choices=ESCOLHAS_PRODUTO,
                            default=CAMISA)

class Camisa(Produto):   

    # the choices here are very long, so i omitted them

    cor = models.CharField(max_length = 40,
                                    choices=CORES_CAMISA,
                                    ) 
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length = 50,
                              choices=MODELO_CAMISA,
                              )
    tamanho= models.CharField(max_length = 50,
                              choices=TAMANHO_CAMISA,
                              )
    quantidade = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.modelo
```

Then i have a form to gather some data and save it on the database. But since it's an inventory control app, if a record already exists, i want the app to update the quantity. If it doesn't exist, i want it to create the record. My view code is below:

```
def index(request):
    # template = loader.get_template('recados/index.html')
    produtos_estoque = Camisa.objects.all()
    template = 'estoque/index.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CamisaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            produto_atualizar = Camisa.objects.get(modelo = request.POST[modelo], cor = request.POST[cor], tamanho = request.POST[tamanho])
            if produto_atualizar:
                produto_atualizar.quantidade = request.POST[quantidade]
            else:
                produto_atualizar = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        form = CamisaForm()
    return render_to_response(template, { 'form': form, 'produtos_estoque': produtos_estoque }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The trace from the error is the following:

```
NameError at /estoque/

global name 'modelo' is not defined
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: A general bit of advice: You clearly have excellent English skills- you should try to make a habit of [coding in English](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/the-ugly-american-programmer.html).

Comment: Oh, thanks for the advice. I'm brazilian, and since i'm just learning and doing some apps to motivate myself to learn, i never thought about that. But it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably here:

```
modelo = request.POST[modelo]
```

There is no `modelo` variable, so most likely you mean this:

```
modelo = request.POST['modelo']
```

The same goes for the other dictionary accesses on that line of code.